# Petición cabeceras http

Tags: http, cabeceras-http, telnet

Tengo que acceder a una página en concreto www.pangea.org, la cual permite tener el idioma de ésta en castellano o en catalán. El caso es que me piden hacer una petición telnet a esta página indicando en la petición el idioma con el que quiero que me muestre la información.

Por defecto sale en catalán así que tengo que cambiarla a español.

¿Que cabecera debo usar para esa funcionalidad?